# Access to the path C:\ is denied in rest service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, rest

I have developed restful service such a way that it gets the data from share point site in json format and creates FormatedProductDetail.json file in drive C:\inetpub\ProductSelector

Below is the code to create a json file in c drive.

```
string Jsondata = serialize.Serialize(serviceResponse);
using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
{    
    myWebClient.UploadString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["outputFilePath"], Jsondata);   
}
```

below is the code from web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    <add key="inputFilePath" value="~/products.json"/>
    <!--<add key="outputFilePath" value="C:\FormatedProductDetail.txt"/>-->
    <add key="outputFilePath" value="C:\inetpub\ProductSelector\FormatedProductDetail.json"/>
</appSettings>
```

I have access only for C:\inetpub\ProductSelector but not c:\ but still I am getting the error from postman as

> Access to the path
>   'C:\inetpub\ProductSelector\FormatedProductDetail.json' is denied.

Comment: Who has access? You or the user that your application runs under?

Comment: do your application has access write to the folder? you must ensure the user that runs your application pool and your application has access to the folder.

Comment: I have access. When I try run through browser also from Postman i am getting error  "Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\ProductSelector\FormatedProductDetail.json' is denied.

Answer (score 2):

The IIS application pool user account needs access to the folder

Comment: Glen Thomas can you please let me know  how to do that?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using to host the application?

Comment: version 8.5.9600.16384

Comment: Use [this guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731755(v=ws.10).aspx) to find the application pool that the website is using and then see what Windows user account the pool is using. Then grant security permissions on the folder for that user account, or change the application pool user account to another (maybe your own)

Comment: Glen Thomas, your solution helped me to resolve the issue. You are great..Thank you

Comment: @anithalm You can click the tick to accept answer. Thanks :)